# Magento "There has been an error processing your request" after change permisions of local.xml

Tags: php, xml, ssh, magento-1.9

I changed the permisions of the file "app/etc/local.xml" in my Magento and now can´t process request.

> "There has been an error processing your request"

I trying return to original values with 'XXX' and '777' permisions and nothing, Magento Still Crashed.

The log say this.

*The error`a:4:{i:0;s:65:"dbModel read resource does not implement Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract";i:1;s:1372:"#0 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(134): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->setConnection(false)

#1 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1354): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->__construct(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))

#2 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1386): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('core_resource/w...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))

#3 /var/www/magento/app/Mage.php(491): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getResourceModelInstance('core/website_co...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))

#4 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(208): Mage::getResourceModel('core/website_co...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))

#5 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(213): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getResourceCollection()

#6 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(619): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getCollection()

#7 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(477): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initStores()

#8 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(360): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initCurrentStore('', 'store')

#9 /var/www/magento/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)

#10 /var/www/magento/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')

#11 {main}";s:3:"url";s:37:"/magento/index.php/M2ePro/cron/index/";s:11:"script_name";s:18:"/magento/index.php";}`
*

Comment: Please check and confirm the database details given in local.xml is correct.

Comment: all is correct the solution was delete the cache in var/cache

Answer (score 0):

- Go to app/etc/local.xml > permision > change Value number for 644
- Delete all in var/chache